# What are the bounds on the class number of a cyclotomic field with regulator power of 2?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

Let $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ be the $n$th cyclotomic field with $n$ being a power of $2$. What is the best known asymptotic upper bound on the class number of  $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ as n grows? Can we say something better for at least a fraction of the fields. For example, can we say that a large fraction of these fields have class number bounded asymptotically by a polynomial in $n$.

Any heuristics?

Comment: The class number $h$ of a cyclotomic field is the product of the "plus part" $h^+$, which is the class number of the maximal real subfield of the cyclotomic field, and the "minus part" $h^-$, which is defined to be $h/h^+$.  The minus part is relatively well understood, and is related to Bernoulli numbers.  The "plus part" is much more difficult.  For $n$ a power of 2, there is a well-known conjecture that that $h^+ = 1$.  This is called "Weber's class number problem."

Answer (score 6):

Let $h_n$ denote the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$.  Then we can decompose $h_n$ into the "plus part" and "minus part":
$$h_n = h^+_n h^-_n,$$
where $h^+_n$ is the class number of the maximal real subfield $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n + \zeta_n^{-1})$, and $h^-_n$ is defined (somewhat tautologically) to be $h_n / h^+_n$.

The "minus part" $h^-_n$ is well understood, and we even have an asymptotic (see Washington, "Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields," pg. 45):
$$\log{h^-_n} \sim \frac{1}{4}\phi(n)\log{n},$$
where $\phi$ is the Euler totient function.

Thus, $h^-$ grows exponentially in $n$, and is not bounded by any polynomial in $n$.

The "plus part" is trickier.  There is a conjecture that $h^+_n = 1$ if $n$ is a power of 2.  The best known upper bounds on such $h^+_n$ with $n=2^k$ are based on cyclotomic regulators and lower bounds of relative regulators.  But this still gives bounds which grow exponentially in $n$, so are quite poor.  I can give a more precise answer about this if anyone is interested.

In any event, the class number $h_n = h^+_n h^-_n$ will grow exponentially in $n$.

Comment: I am curious about those relative regulators. Could you please explain further ?